# Why is "Evaluation of lambda expressions is not valid in the debugger"?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, lambda

I have a seemingly innocent code snippet, which I typed into Visual Studio 2008 *Immediate Window*.

```
? results.Join(lstDocs, Function(docID) docID)
Evaluation of lambda expressions is not valid in the debugger.
```

As the message says, it's not possible to call a lambda expression in the debugger.

**Why is it not allowed?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here: [Why is LINQ absent from debugger windows?](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2009/08/26/why-no-linq-in-debugger-windows.aspx)

And this previous question: [VS debugging “quick watch” tool and lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725499/vs-debugging-quick-watch-tool-and-lambda-expressions)

In short, complexity.

Comment: @Jason: Your summary sums it up right, according to what I read. Thanks.

Comment: Really, really missing the capability of a Rails console in making this transition to EF/.NET.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763138.aspx

It's impossible by design. Lambda expressions need to generate code on the fly in the immediate window. The debugger and/or evaluater cannot handle this. If you really want to know why, ask the developers of VS. Maybe this is an upcoming feature somewhen. Lambda expressions is a bearly new feature