# Linq sum value filtered by datetime

Tags: asp.net, linq

in my system user choose start time and end time and then my system show user 
sum  of total prices between this date time.

```
 TotalRate = room.Prices.Where( hrp => hrp.ValidStartAt<= hotelSearchModel.StartAt.Value &&
  hrp.ValidEndAt >= hotelSearchModel.StartAt.Value).Sum(p => p.NightPriceRate),
```

i want to debug this but it says Expression cannot contain lambda expressions
how can i debug this
and what is my mistake with this code?

Comment: Are you sure this line has error ? It seems haven't any problem.

Comment: When you say "I want to debug this", are you trying that in the Immediate\Watchs windows? If so, be aware that lamdas are not allowed there, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725499/vs-debugging-quick-watch-tool-and-lambda-expressions

Comment: _what is my mistake_ Well, what happens? Unexpected results? Exception?

Comment: no exception unexpected results.it sum but ressult is wrong

Comment: A great place to start is to include a line of debug code that shows you what your result set looks like before you sum it up: `var prices = room.Prices.Where( hrp => hrp.ValidStartAt<= hotelSearchModel.StartAt.Value && hrp.ValidEndAt >= hotelSearchModel.StartAt.Value);`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly Visual Studio does not support LINQ in Expressions but for such not complicated queries http://www.linqpad.net/ probably can be usefull.

Hope it will help.