# How to debug a Linq Lambda Expression?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, debugging, lambda

I am using Entity Framework and Linq to Entitites.

I would like to know if there is any way in Visual Studio 2012 to debug this code, step by step.
At the moment when placing a break point, the cursor goes over it but does not step inside.

I am more interested to see the value of x.e... not the sql generated for example.

Notes: I'm fine with using other tools or Visual Studio plugins.

```
          IEnumerable<EventPushNotification> eventToPushCollage = eventsForEvaluation
                    .GroupJoin(eventCustomRepository.FindAllPushedEvents(),
                        e => e.Id,
                        p => p.PushedEventId,
                        (e, p) => new { e, p })
                     .Where(x => x.e.DateTimeStart > currentDateTime &&
                        currentDateTime >= x.e.DateTimeStart.AddMinutes(defaultReminders) &&     //  Data from default reminder for collage event in web.config  
                        x.p.Count() == 0)                                           // Check if the Event has not being already pushed
                     .Select(y => new EventPushNotification
                     {
                         Id = y.e.Id,
                         EventTitle = y.e.EventTitle,
                         DateTimeStart = y.e.DateTimeStart,
                         DateTimeEnd = y.e.DateTimeEnd,
                         Location = y.e.Location,
                         Description = y.e.Description,
                         DeviceToken = y.e.DeviceToken
                     });
```

Comment: You can right-click on one of the lambdas and select "Breakpoint -> Insert Breakpoint". This will highlight just the lambda.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015.aspx

VS-2015 will support this. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You [*can't*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725499/vs-debugging-quick-watch-tool-and-lambda-expressions) debug a Lambda expression if you're using a Linq to Entities provider.

But you can [take a look](http://www.linqpad.net/) at what SQL it translate into. 
Also if you are willing to suffer a performance hit - you could load it all into Linq to obejcts - and do a [Step by step](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/linq-secrets-revealed-chaining-and-debugging/)

Comment: I am not going to downvote but have a look below at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22518808/2754848 and find a solution that works pretty well.

Comment: @Daved hmmm Leniel would be right *if* OP was using LinqToObjects - but this is not OP's case. OP's lambda is LinqToEntities - and one *cant* debug those like Leiel suggest. I have opdated my answer

Comment: Fair enough. I read right over that part. Thanks for editing your solution as well. Linq to Obj look below. Linq to Entity look above :)

Comment: @JensKloster Please note that statement is no longer true - I work on a commercial extension to VS called OzCode. We added [LINQ Debugging in v3.0](https://blog.oz-code.com/enter-the-era-of-linq-debugging-with-the-ozcode-early-access-program/) and [support for LINQ2Entities](https://blog.oz-code.com/new-version-announced-debugging-linq-entity-framework-queries/) in v3.1

Answer (score 91):

Make sure you read the official MSDN doc on this matter:

[Debugging LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385795.aspx#bkmk_steppingandlinq)

and please vote for this suggestion on Visual Studio's User Voice page:

[Debug Lambda expressions](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2049821-debug-lambda-expressions)

[Allon Guralnek](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/users/25166487-allon-guralnek) comments on *March 18, 2014 12:37 PM* about a way of setting a breakpoint with the keyboard only:

> @Anonymous: You can do this today by setting a breakpoint inside the
>   lambda, thereby enabling you to inspect each value that comes in and
>   out of the lambda. As far as I know, you can't set a breakpoint inside
>   a lambda using the mouse, you must use the keyboard. Put the cursor
>   inside the lambda body (e.g. on the first token, or anything after the
>   => and the whitespace that follows) then press F9 (or whatever keyboard shortcut you use to place a breakpoint). Only the inside of
>   the lambda statement will turn red, and the debugger will break there
>   for each item the lambda is evaluated against (so for an array of 100
>   items, using .Where() will cause the breakpoint to hit 100 times).

Here's it in action in my current Visual Studio 2013:

[image]

As you can see it works pretty well and allows us to see the value of a given property being tested. This is for sure an awesome tool/life saver! :)

Comment: Cool, your tip just helped me debug through various lambda expressions which were a completely black box to me. Thanks

Comment: This looks good in the editor (VS2013) (only lambda is red), but when staritng debug, the whole statement becomes red for me and the debugger breaks on the outer statement. :(     Ideas?

Comment: Is this not the answer?

Comment: I am in 2022, and I am not able to do that. why?????

Answer (score 8):

You can add breakpoints on any of your own code.

So put the cursor at 'x.e', and press F9.

Comment: Yes you can put breakpoints, but they are not going to be hit if the code is executed by Entity Framework (Linq to Entities).

Answer (score 3):

For any future readers, this has now been included in Visual Studio. Starting from Visual Studio 2015 Preview, you can now debug lambda expression during debugging. All debug windows including Watch, QuickWatch and Immediate support lambda expression evaluation. You can read more about this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to see values of `x` nor `e` variables because linq to orm is not executed it is translated/interpreted to generate an sql query.

Answer (score 0):

I had to 'Enable Just My Code' in Tools/Options/Debugging.
To see the different results between Lambda-methods, I've put .ToList() between them.

Comment: i have VS 2015 enterprise edition, made this setting but still does not work

Answer (score 0):

The debug run on function called with lambda expression if you use ToList().

Example

```
bool aFunction(int x) { return x < 10; }
var l = new List<int>() { 5, 6, 11 }.Where(el => aFunction(el)).ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how to this directly in Visual Studio, but you should have a look at LinqPad: http://www.linqpad.net/