# Debug Lambda expressions in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, lambda

I am querying a SQL Server database from my ASP.net application in C#. Following is a part of my database schema.

[image]

I wrote following expression to get data from the database.

```
var query = db.DBMovies.Where(ent => ent.Id == Id).Join(db.DBCategories,
    r => r.Id,
    l => l.CategoryId,
    (r, l) => new
    {
       Id = r.Id,
       MovieName = r.Name,
       Year = r.Year,
       Category = r.Genre,
       PosterURL = r.PosterURL,
});

foreach (var movie in query)
{
    //something
}
```

In the part `ent.Id == Id`, the `Id` in the right refers to a parameter value. I referred [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669071.aspx) tutorial, but when I execute this, the execution does not get inside the foreach loop. I created a breakpoint inside the foreach loop and noticed that it didn't hit. Can somebody help me to find out the issue? And please suggest a way to quick watch the values returned by a lambda expression if possible.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

I changed the query as I have made a huge mistake first time, but I don't see any success even now.

```
var query = db.DBMovieToCategory.Where(ent => ent.CategoryId == Id).Join(db.DBMovies,
r => r.MovieId,
l => l.Id,
(r, l) => new
{
    Id = l.Id,
    MovieName = l.Name,
    Year = l.Year,
    Category = l.Genre,
    PosterURL = l.PosterURL,
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231101/how-to-debug-a-linq-lambda-expression

Comment: so the result query is null?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like you're trying to join Movies to Categories by matching the Movie id to the Category id.  That would only return you any records by coincidence.

Comment: visual studio is unable to debug lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to join Movies to Categories by matching the Movie id to the Category id.  Since the IDs are assigned independently, you will only get records back if by chance you have a Movie and a Category with the same ID.

Getting no records back would be why you never enter the `foreach` loop.

I see no relationships defined in your model, so DBMovies, DBCategories, and DBMoviesToCategories don't "know" they're related to each other.

Comment: Thank you Ann L. It is really really my bad. Thank you for pointing that. I had to change it a lot. THanks.

Comment: Btw, I didn't add any foreign key relationships between the tables as you mentioned. Isn't it ok to get the results just by joining them?

Comment: Its ok. I figured it out. Now its ok. Thank you.