# Why can't you have a lambda in a conditional breakpoint in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, lambda, conditional-breakpoint

Say I have the following method:

```
public List<List<int>> DoSomething () {
    List<List<int>> result;

    //Do some things

    return result; //Would like to breakpoint here
}
```

I try to have a conditional breakpoint such as:

```
result.Any(i => i.Any(j => j < 0))
```

I get an error saying you cannot have lambda expressions in conditional breakpoints. Why is that?

Comment: Because the team did not implement, test and release that feature.

Comment: Since the breakpoint is a debugging feature, I would imagine the same reasoning from here applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725499/vs-debugging-quick-watch-tool-and-lambda-expressions.

Comment: Thanks @xDaevax I didn't see the question. Although, that question is 5 and a half years old so perhaps there is a more recent explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The feature has been implemented in VS2015! You can now use lambda expressions in conditional breakpoints, watches and in the immediate window.

---

The only answer to this question is a boring "because they did not implement the feature". I suppose the cost vs benefit of this feature was simply not worth the development time.

An alternative to a conditional breakpoint would be to add the following code

```
if (result.Any(i => i.Any(j => j < 0)))
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Not very pretty and of course you'll want to remove that once your debugging session is over but it gets the job done.

Comment: Thank you for providing a constructive response. You suggestion will help me in lieu of this limitation.