# "Expression not supported" when debugging lambda expressions

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, lambda

I'm trying to [debug lambda expressions with Visual Studio 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/12/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015/) while in debug mode on an Android device. If I put

```
this.customerList.Where(p => p.LastName == "Doe").ToList()
```

in the *Watch* or *Immediate Window* I get

> Expression not supported.

I'm doing this after the debugger stopped at the breakpoint. If I don't use the breakpoint I get

> The expression cannot be evaluated while in run mode.

What I'm doing wrong?

The options stated in [lambda expressions in immediate window for VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559399/lambda-expressions-in-immediate-window-for-vs2015) are grayed out and not ticked, while in debug mode.

**Edit**

I tried the example code from [Tatranskymedved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42975603/expression-not-supported-when-debugging-lambda-expressions?noredirect=1#comment73047349_42975603) with the same result:

[image: Debugging lambda expression not possible]

My guess is that debugging lambda expression is not possible with Xamarin. I tried it on device and on simulator and both are showing the same result. Another possibility would be that I have to change some debugger settings. Here I tried to disable `Use Fast Deployment (debug mode only)` and `Use Shared Runtime` without success.

Comment: Whats the problem of `Expression not supported.`? What did you expect? (or not). It's probably because the `this.customerList.Where(p => p.LastName == "Doe")` returns an `IQueryable<>`

Comment: What exactly is `customerList`?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: I expect to get an object, which satisfy the condition, where I could dig in deeper to inspect some variables. Now I have 300+ entries in the list and I don't want to click through all of this to inspect my object. An alternative solution would be write the query directly in the code, recompile, debug and inspect. The above mentioned feature would come in handy. Shouldn't `ToList()` or `ToArray()` handle this?

Comment: @juharr: Simplified said a `List<Person>`, where `Person` inherits finally from `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @testing I just tried it myself, watching both `list.Where()` and `list.Where().ToList()` worked well. Could You please add definition of Your `Customer` class? http://imgur.com/a/4iDkA

Comment: Also works in immediate window. When i started debugging, watch shows me the same message as to You, but once I clicked on the "ring arrow", it evaluates the query and gave me the results.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved: Thanks for your response. There is no "ring arrow" in my case. On which machine have you tested your code? I'm running directly on an Android tablet and I can imagine that this can cause the issue or I have to change some debugger settings. I could provide you the full object, but that would be very big. I think I'll try a very simple example project and then I update my question with the code of this example.

Comment: So that might be the issue. I run the code on normal laptop with win10.

Comment: I just tried on Xamarin myself, same behavior as You have.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved: In my screenshot I now noted that he writes at the bottom *This item does not support previewing*. Is this related?

Comment: I have not found any post/other question on SO (nobody works with that.. muhehe). Downgrade target .NET version (for normal app) and it still works well. Probably this sort of debugging is not supported on Xa. Got no clue.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved: Thanks for your confirmation, that this also doesn't work on your side. Do you want to post this as an answer? I find this funny, when some pro user downvote and vote for closing this question, while not really understanding the issue (but think that this is only an easy question like a typo) ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After running several tests (no post/article on this topic found as a reference), I came to verdict that debugging of Lambda expressions does not work **on Xamarin** with Xamarin debugger.

Same code/expression does normally work on standard application:

[image: a]

This seems to be unrelated to version of .NET, as downgrading to version 4.0 (on Console app), still provide same debug results.

I have noted that in properties of Android project, there is an option called "debugger" and values to choose from: **Xamarin, Microsoft** Standard debug of Console app is most likely with the **Microsoft** one - which might have full support of debugging the Lambda expression.

Comment: For debugger I only have `.Net (Xamarin)` and `C++` under the tab *Packaging* in *Android Options*.

Comment: @testing - Did you found any solution for this?

Comment: @AbrahamJohn: No, I've given it up. But since the question is some years old it could be that Xamarin has updated it's debugger. Does the issue still exists today?

Comment: @testing 12/07/2022, problem still here.