# Invalid expression term '.' null-conditional, watch window and immediate window not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, watch-window

I've got the exact same problem as here [VS2015 watch window does not accept the null-conditional syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384939/vs2015-watch-window-does-not-accept-the-null-conditional-syntax?rq=1)

I'm running VS 2017, .net 4.7.2 and I selected C# 7.3

I have updated Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompiterPlatform to 2.0.1
and Microsoft.Net.Compilers to 2.10.0

Any idea anyone, please?

The picture from other issue says everything

[image]

Basically looks it doesn't like null-conditional syntax in watch window and immediate window.

Comment: Can you give us a quick [mcve]? The *new* "create question guide" should have mentioned to do this, it saves us having to go to a duplicate issue and read that question to repro your issue. Do you have either `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` or `Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators` ticked? Some more info would be helpful. I'm just guessing now.

Comment: added extra info

Comment: yes, I did have Use Managed Compatibility Mode checked. Thanks a lot for help :)

Comment: why do you have the **@** symbol prefix?

Comment: this isn't my code, I took that screenshot from another issue I linked in the description.

Comment: Can you untick `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/36559817/495455? If that doesn't work can you provide a [mcve]? Just a 2 line repro?